# Lyx : change default list settings to numeric

Tags: formatting, lyx, lists

Current version of Lyx 2.3.4.2, has a list settings as :

```
1.
  a)
  b)
```

I would like to change this default to :

```
1.
  1.1.
  1.2.
```

I tried :

```
\setenumerate{label=(\alph*)}
```

in Latex Preamble but that doesn't seem to do anything. What or how should I do to achieve this ?

*edit : enumitem is installed in layout as advised in documentation.*

**edit 2 :**

1. open Lyx
2. add enumitem.module from : [doc](https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/Enumitem)
3. enable it in Document -> settings -> modules
4. put your line of code in empty : Document -> settings -> Latex Preamble
5. apply as default
6. apply and restart

- Document class is set to : KOMA Script Book

Thanks

Comment: Use `\setlist[enumerate,2]{label*=\arabic*.}`. The starred label appends the second level  counter to the parent counter.

Comment: Thanks but letter list still holds, I don't know why : it didn't change anything.

Comment: In this case,  please post a minimal code reproducing the problem.

Comment: Sorry I'm nw to Lyx and I don't unerstand what you mean : I don't have any code, I just want to have numerical lists in a new document in Lyx. I add what I did do in an edit but that's all I have.

Comment: @JohnDoe make sure you check the PDF output. When you use custom LaTeX, LyX will not show the correct display.

Comment: @scottkosty : Yeah, I know I saw that somewhere in the doc : and I did forgot. THANKS Scott ! Yes it was. :)
Bernard please make your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @JohnDoe I've been using LyX for years and I still forget to do that sometimes :). By the way, this is something that I would like to spend time on fixing in LyX (i.e., you would not have to use custom LaTeX and the LyX display would be correct), but I don't think I would get to it for many years.

Comment: @Scott I shall only encourage you to do so.. One's always can find solace when seeing what's one really means. :)